# when i run my index file following error occure

Tags: zend-framework

When I run my index file following error occure
my index file is under
`var/www/giftercity/dev/public/index.php`

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "multidb" not found' in /var/www/Giftercity_backup/dev/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:692 
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/Giftercity_backup/dev/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(627): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('multidb') 
#1 /var/www/Giftercity_backup/dev/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(584): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap('multidb') 
#2 /var/www/Giftercity_backup/dev/application/Bootstrap.php(336): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap('multidb') 
#3 /var/www/Giftercity_backup/dev/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(667): Bootstrap->_initUser() 
#4 /var/www/Giftercity_backup/dev/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(620): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('user') 
#5 /var/www/Giftercity_backup/dev/library/Zend/A in /var/www/Giftercity_backup/dev/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php on line 692
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from your question, You tried to bootstrap the multidb Resource.

I've personally just done this in my application.ini

```
    resources.multidb.defaultMetadataCache = "database"

    resources.multidb.db1.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
    resources.multidb.db1.host = "localhost"
    resources.multidb.db1.username = "webuser"
    resources.multidb.db1.password = "XXXX"
    resources.multidb.db1.dbname = "db1"
    resources.multidb.db1.default = true

    resources.multidb.db2.adapter = "pdo_pgsql"
    resources.multidb.db2.host = "example.com"
    resources.multidb.db2.username = "dba"
    resources.multidb.db2.password = "notthatpublic"
    resources.multidb.db2.dbname = "db2"
```

and then created a function in my bootstrap

```
protected function _initDb()
{
    $resource = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');
    Zend_Registry::set("multidb", $resource);
}
```

There are no more steps involved into bootstrapping multidb, as far as I know.